# Does one need to reserve threads for event loops or reuse event loops when using asyncio.run in a multi worker setup?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I have an (nginx + gunicorn) server that has a pre-specified number of workers which serve requests that involve downloadng a specified list of images and processing them.

I have an image download routine in Python 3.8 that uses an async routine `download_image` to download a single image from a URL which is then wrapped by another async routine `download_images` that gathers these images over a list of URLs.

```py
async def download_image(url, timeout, sem):
    async with sem:
        with requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=timeout) as remote_response:
            image_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(remote_response.raw.read()), dtype="uint8")
            image_decoded = cv2.imdecode(image_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image_color_corrected = cv2.cvtColor(image_decoded, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            return image_decoded, image_color_corrected

async def download_images(image_url_list):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(20)
    return await asyncio.gather(
        *[download_image(url, 5, sem) for url in image_url_list], 
        return_exceptions=True
    )
```

This is then called for each request that lands in a worker from the main function of that worker as follows:

```py
images = asyncio.run(download_images(input_requests, cfg))
```

There is a couple of problems I'm having with this setup:

- **Not reusing event loops**: I'm using `asyncio.run()` for every request which does not feel like the best way of doing things. Surely I must reuse event loops to serve all the requests landing within a single worker?
- **Errors seen in high load scenarios**: When I run this code with just a few workers it works just as expected. However, if I increase the number of workers in the server and expose the sever to heavy load I start getting errors saying `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` even though I only ever call it from the synchronous main function. I have a feeling that the increased context switching from the larger load of requests is preempting the threads in use by some of the async download functions which may be in an event loop. Is this possible? If not what could be the culprit? Is there any way to reserve threads for event loops which cannot be preempted by the OS for other loads?

Comment: What web framework are you using? You might want to switch to something asyncio-aware like Quart or FastAPI.

Comment: I am using the AWS sagemaker inference container which spawns a server with a pre-specified number of threads using nginx+gunicorn+wsgi. Could you clarify why is using async coroutines which I am managing end-to-end within my main function, a problem for even a non async-aware server?

Comment: I have no idea what the AWS sagemaker inference container is, but I doubt a non asyncio-aware framework is a problem unless your goal is to “reuse event loops to serve all requests landing with a single worker.”